# hide get parameters completely without affecting the url using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, url-rewriting, get

I have my website: www.testurl.com. The index.php first checks the client's device and redirects to the mobile version and desktop version accordingly.

However, while getting redirected to the desktop version, I get the url `www.testurl.com/index.shtml?redirect=false`. I want to hide the `?redirect=false` part using htaccess. How can I do that? Due to my logic, I can't use post requests.

Comment: any other solution? I cant use post..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your index.php put it there because it needs it. You can't simply *hide* it by using directives in an htaccess file.

I'm going to assume that the `redirect=false` query string is to let `index.php` know not to redirect *again* based on the user-agent. So how does rules in htaccess know whether a request has been redirected? It seems like the `index.php` needs to be able to look at the version of the site that's being request. If it's a mobile user-agent, and it's accessing the mobile version of the site, don't redirect. If it's a desktop user-agent and it's accessing the desktop version of the site, don't redirect. This way you don't need the `redirect=false` query string.

Comment: basically index.php redirects to index.shtml if desktop agent is detected. However , if someone directly accesses index.shtml through mobile , they will obviously get the desktop site. Thats why I put a simple javascript to catch the redirect parameter. But then I want to hide that. Thats the main problem

Comment: @ArpitGaur You can't just hide it with htaccess. You need to solve the problem without having to use it. If someone directly accesses index.shtml through mobile, check the user-agent and direct them to the mobile version.

Comment: I think its time to use cookies now :(

Comment: @ArpitGaur I thought about mentioning cookies but it still depends on implementation. Mobile browser goes to desktop site, gets redirect + gets a cookie. Later on, same browser (which still has cookie) goes to desktop site again, it has cookie, won't get redirected.